# Finding Closest Edge to a Point in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I need to find 2 closest edges to a point within a picturebox.I'm using the following method

```
 void findclosestedges(Point p)
        {


            //Xedge=1 -- Left Edge is closer to Point 2--Right Edge 
            int Xedge,Yedge;
            //Finding closest Left/Right Edge
            if (p.X < (Width - p.X))
            {
                Xedge = 1;
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " ";
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " left";
            }
            else
            {
                Xedge = 2;
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " ";
                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " right";
            }

            //Finding closest Top/Bottom Edge

            if (p.Y < (Height - p.Y))
            {
                Yedge = 1;

                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " top";
            }
            else
            {
                Yedge = 2;

                LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " bottom";
            }

        }
```

Is my approach correct? Are there any caveats for this approach?

Please advice.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a code review.  If so, you might want to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem it set up correctly. Since I know the original problem what you actually need to do is find the alignment of a rectangle in a larger rectangle. Since the inner rectangle will contain  text of varying length and sizes you need to compare the delta_x_left = innerRect.X  and delta_x_right = outer.Right - inner.Right.  then set deltaDelta =  delta_x_right - delta_x_left . if  deltaDelta > 0 -> rightAligned else left aligned. you can also test for math.abs(delatDelta) y someLimit to detect a centered position..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this might not be the correct place since your code is working, at least as far as i know?

But a few comments might be that i am not sure why you set the text to a value and then on the next row add to it?

```
LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " ";
LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text + " left";
```

Why not just do it directly:

```
LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = " " + " left";
```

Or of course the correct way:

```
LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = "  left";
```

I would also shorten down the code like the following:

```
    void findclosestedges(Point p) {
        int Xedge = p.X < (Width - p.X) ? 1 : 2;
        int Yedge = p.Y < (Height - p.Y) ? 1 : 2;

        LaunchOrigin2.closestedge.Text = (Xedge == 1 ? "  left" : "  right") + (Yedge == 1 ? " top" : " bottom");
    }
```

But that is just my two cents...